# Is there a way to set different frame sizes for different layers in a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, transparency, calayer

Right now I have a UIScrollView and a semi-transparent top and bottom bar which go over it. The UIScrollView contains a large UIImageView that is pannable and zoomable.

I want to be able to toggle the image and darken everything around a certain part of the image, but have the transparency mesh perfectly with the top/bottom bars which are semi-transparent. Since the content is scrollable/zoomable, if I darken the image itself, anytime that part goes under the top/bottom bars it will double darken.

I tried to solve this dilemma by creating a smaller UIScrollView that sits nested between the top and bottom bars, and sending zoom/pan commands to it in an attempt to mirror the UIScrollView below it, but that didn't work too nicely. It was a nightmare trying to sync the animations (I tried copying over the zoomScale/contentOffset in zoomDidScroll, sending the zoom/pan animation to each UIScrollView individually, using KVO, etc).

Is there any way I can set different frame sizes/cut-off points for each individual layer? Or perhaps each UIImageView subview? I'm open to any other proposed solutions as well, this has really been driving me up the wall. I appreciate the help.

What it's like before toggle:
[image]

What I want after toggle:
[image]

Comment: When you darken everything around the image, could you set the background color of the top and bottom bars to a clear color?

Comment: That's actually pretty brilliant, don't know why I didn't think of this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: glad that works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not cover the "center" part with another semi-transparent view to match the tool bars, then use a mask on the layer to make the part of it you wish fully transparent?

Comment: I could do that, but then I wouldn't be able to do any panning/zooming on the UIScrollView without having to calculate the changes in real-time and update the mask on the layer of the center semi-transparent view. Probably more complicated than having a UIScrollView that sits on top which I had before, but is too much of a headache to use. Edit: Unless there's an easy way to calculate and update the center layer accordingly, not sure if there is.

Comment: What you are trying to do is inherently complex, so any solution will be difficult to implement.